# How to get distinct values and count its unrepeatable values? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `SoldCars`.

```
Id_Car                               Id_Color                         time
8                                      2                          2015-02-11
8                                      4                          2015-03-11
8                                      2                          2015-04-11
5                                      2                          2015-05-11
8                                      3                          2015-08-11
```

I would like to query to get the following rowset:

```
Id_car          CountColors
8                   3
5                   1
```

Where `Id_car` is unique `Id_Car` and `CountColors` is count of distinct quantity of colors.

I've tried a lot of SQL queries, but the result is far from good.

For Example:

```
Select dictinct Id_Car, count(Id_Color) as CountColors from SoldCars group by Id_car
```

Comment: Select Id_Car, count(DISTINCT Id_Color) as CountColors from SoldCars group by Id_car

Comment: @TabAlleman please answer and I'll mark it

Comment: Appreciate the offer, but since a duplicate was identified, please just delete or leave it closed.   Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Id_car, count(DISTINCT Id_Color) AS CountColors FROM SoldCars GROUP BY Id_car
```

This should do the job :)